# ActiveRecord - destroy does not update parent object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Got the following has one relation

```
class x
 has_one y
end

class y
 belongs_to x
end

x.create_y
x.y.present? #true

x.y.destroy
x.y.present? #true
x.reload.y.present? #false
```

I understand that this, after destroy parent still referenced a deleted object, is the expected behavior, but, is there a way to destroy the relation and update the parent in single line ? or I must call reload?

Comment: Yes it persists but what user case would be problematic ?

Answer (score -1):

try using `has_one y, dependent: :destroy`

Refer this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-dependent

Comment: I'm using it.. it's not related to the questions.